# What are alternative ways to implement a symbol table in a compiler?

Tags: python, design-patterns, compiler-construction, visitor-pattern, symbol-table

I'm writing a compiler for one of my classes this semester, and although I have a working implementation of a symbol table, I am a bit uncomfortable with its implementation.
Since I'm doing the project in Python, I decided to go with an OO approach and my AST nodes all have an `accept` method to implement the visitor pattern. I have `preVisit` and `postVisit` methods for all types of nodes, and I use them to enter/exit new scopes and add new bindings to the table. It works, but I feel uneasy about the fact that my symbol table is "ephemeral" and bound to this visitor class. I implemented type checking by subclassing the symbol table visitor class, and I needed to be extremely careful with my calls to the super class, to place them exactly at the correct place. The fragility of this implementation and the fact that any phase of the compiler will need to be tightly coupled to the visitor class is causing me some unease.

I was wondering in what other ways people typically implement symbol tables? Since that information is purely static, could it be added directly into the AST nodes? Is there a way to create a table that could be created once and symbols could be looked up in the correct context? Also, how do the purely functional programmers attack this problem?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, TBH, but surely you can have each table as a `collections.ChainMap` (or similar) of the current and outside scopes. Then you attach those to your AST or some mapping of such and the visitor can just keep a reference to the current scope's symbol table.

Comment: @Veedrac: that's pretty much what I was wondering; is it a common pattern in compiler design to attach the symbol table to the AST? I really like the idea, because then any method of traversing the AST is fine since the symbol information is readily available. I'm a bit worried about space usage however. I imagine that by having only the information declared in the current scope available and with a mechanism to look into the upper scopes, that could work.  Thanks for taking the time to comment.